# scala.io.source.fromFile with sbt subProjects reading from root resource folder

Tags: scala, sbt

I have a sbt build with multiple subProjects, when trying to use `scala.io.source.fromFile` it tries to read files from the root project and not from each individual subProject. This is what I need in some cases but in others I want to use the root resource.

What is the idiomatic way of reading from subproject and root resource folders in SBT with subprojects?

Comment: Did the answer below help in any way? I can try to make it more helpful if you have any feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on which scope you are calling `resourceDirectory` from. Here is an example of build with one root project and two sub-projects (from sbt REPL):

```
> resourceDirectory
[info] alpha/compile:resourceDirectory
[info]  /Users/xyz/sbt-tutorial/sub-projects/sub-a/src/main/resources
[info] beta/compile:resourceDirectory
[info]  /Users/xyz/sbt-tutorial/sub-projects/sub-b/src/main/resources
[info] root/compile:resourceDirectory
[info]  /Users/xyz/sbt-tutorial/sub-projects/src/main/resources
```

As you can see, calling `alpha/compile:resourceDirectory` will get you the resource directory for the sub-project called `alpha`.

If you want the sbt DSL notation for this it will be:

```
myTask := {
   val resDir = (resourceDirectory in (alpha, Compile)).value
   ...
}
```

You can replace `alpha` etc. with `ThisBuild` if you want to get the resource directory for the root project.

Comment: But how come some resources are found. It looks like fromFile is the only one having problem. Application config and logback are picked up correct from the subprojects resources.

Comment: can you show me where that ask is coded? is it inside the settings of a project or outside? I can help you more if you show me what you have.